# Need to target listview position on click android

Tags: android

I have a situation where I am trying to change the text within a `TextView` on a certain row being clicked in a `ListView`.

The following code shows how I try and do this:

```
    answerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

           TextView selection = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.selection);
           selection.setText("Selection");

       }
   });
```

Currently, when selecting any row from within the list view, the first row sets the text as desired.

How do I incorporate position in this to ensure that the correct row is displaying the text I require?

Thanks!

Comment: what you are doing should be working. I just tried it. selection is your TextView's ID in the list item layout?

Comment: I think I tested it before I changed to the view passed through by the onclick. Before, I was using a final view which would have targeted it differently. The problem is, if I select one, the others within the listview should change and text should be removed or set to null.

Comment: @sark9012 check out my answer, maybe it will help

Comment: I don't know why you are facing problem, I just tried your code which is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

in method :

public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l)

int i gives the position, you can use this.

Comment: Thanks, I know that i gives me the position but how do I incorporate that to target the correct TextView? They are all called the same R.id.selection within my XML file. Could you show an example? :)

Comment: @sark9012: You are doing fine in your method. The TextView will have the same id since you are re-using the same view over and over again and doing different stuff depending on your position.

Answer (score 0):

There you are getting integer value from onItemClick method write switch with i as parameter

Comment: What I don't understand is where I put i into the R.id.selection line?

Comment: you can write switch(i)or use this method ((TextView)view).setText("Hey, I've just been tapped on!");

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an AdapterView.OnItemClickListener. Implement the onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) method. The view you get passed here, is the TextView of the clicked item, so it should be enough to do

((TextView)view).setText("Hey, I've just been tapped on!");

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you need, then you should just iterate over your list of objects inside `onItemClick`, change the property which is used to set the text view to an empty string for every element EXCEPT the i element, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's the most authentic way to do it, but i do it like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout);     
        holder = new StoreHolder();         
        holder.tvData = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_data);
        convertView.setTag(holder);         
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (StoreHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvData.setText("hello");     

    holder.tvData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //Do stuff specific to TextView of particular list row
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

class StoreHolder
{
    TextView tvData;        
}
```

Just create a clickListener in the getview method for the textView and it will work perfectly!